# How do I single commit for multiple queries using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to insert data in to AZURE SQL table by using **pyodbc**. here I am using three SQL queries, when I tried to insert data in to table only last sql statement is inserting.

```
def dbQuery_Multiple_Row(sql,li):
  global cursor, conn
  cursor, conn =db_connection_dev01()
  try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
  except Exception as e:
    li.append("Error-"+str(e))
sql1 = "insert into stars.sampledata values ('Suneel Kummar I', 2, 'Sullurepeta')"
sql2 = "insert into stars.sampledata values ('Suneel Kummar Il', 3, 'Sullurepeta')"
sql3 = "insert into stars.sampledata values ('Suneel Kummar Ill', 4, 'Sullurepeta')"

import pyodbc
sql = [sql1, sql2, sql3]
li = []
dbQuery_Multiple_Row(sql1, li)
dbQuery_Multiple_Row(sql2, li)
dbQuery_Multiple_Row(sql3, li)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

My task is I should commit once for all sql queries, but commit is happening for only last SQL query.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `db_connection_dev01` which opens a new connection.
So, each call to `dbQuery_Multiple_Row` opens a connection, but commit is performed only for the last.
It explains why you see the results of the 3rd query only.
To fix the problem you need to use the same connection.
One way for fix is to open it before `dbQuery_Multiple_Row` and pass it as an argument